# Unable to mock location while using remote access device in aws device farm

Tags: remote-access, aws-device-farm

In remote access devices i was using only iphones
I was able to mock location under auutomated test runs but not in remote access.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to mock GPS location in Remote Access on Device Farm through their offerings. This is a good feature request to implement prior to starting the remote access session.

For further assistance, check out [AWS Device Farm Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193) where you can get assistance with your questions from Device Farm engineers.